# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MethodInfo') in react js app using grpc-web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grpc, grpc-web

I am using grpc-web to communicate with a java backend over gRPC. I am using ReactJS on the frontend which uses grpc-web to interpret the protobuffers.

I am getting this strange error. My protos are correct ( I checked using a reflection tool called "bloom" so the backend is just fine) This somehow seems like an error internal to the grpc libraries I am using in ReactJS.

I get the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'MethodInfo')`

**The above error points to my proto file: *dashboard_services_grpc_web_pb.js***

In this file, it point to this line

`const methodInfo_DashboardService_userLogin = new grpc.web.AbstractClientBase.MethodInfo( ...... );`

I have a hard time solving this because according to my understanding, `grpc.web.AbstractClientBase` is something native to `grpc-web`.

I have also reinstalled my node_modules in hopes that this is a version issue but no avail.

Comment: I have also cleared my npm cache both internally and globally by running `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: I also cloned the project into a  new directory in hopes that it must be some caching issue

Comment: Your title mentions grpc-js. How is grpc-js involved here?

Comment: it was installed in the project so I thought it could be worth mentioning @murgatroid99

Comment: OK, are you using it in some way that relates to this question, and if so, how?

Comment: @murgatroid99 no not using it anywhere

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue because I was using an old release of the executable     `protoc-gen-grpc-web` with respect to the current version of `grpc-web`. Using  version 1.3.0 for both solved the issue for me.
You can download the latest release of `protoc-gen-grpc-web` [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/releases).

Comment: Thank you ... but somehow I could not install `proto-gen-grpc-web` for version 1.3.0. I used the command `npm i proto-gen-grpc-web@1.3.0` but all I got was `No matching version found for protoc-gen-grpc-web@1.3.0.`

Comment: I just checked npm's website, they haven't released version 1.3.0 yet. Do you know how I can add an exe file to my package.json?

Comment: you need to download the executable for your platform and add it to your PATH variable, then $ protoc -I=$DIR echo.proto \
    --js_out=import_style=commonjs:$OUT_DIR \
    --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:$OUT_DIR will generate the right code.

Answer (score 8):

In my case it was happening after cache clear, because we had:

```
"grpc-web": "^1.2.1",
```

and it was installed version `1.3.0` I changed it to:

```
"grpc-web": "1.2.1",
```

and `yarn` again to fix this issue!